# Setting edgesForExtendedLayout affects its parent ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my navigation stack's child, I set `edgesForExtendedLayout = .None`

When I click the back button, the UITableView in my parent gets "moved up", as if the navigation bar doesn't exist. (The Navigation Bar covers the table).

Why does the child's edge setting affect its parent? I only want it to affect the current viewController.

In my parent, this is how I created the UITableView:

```
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, CGRectGetMinY(self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame))
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
    self.tableView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(hex: 0xededed)
    self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
```

Could it be that I am setting the tableView's frame incorrectly?  I want the table to start below the navigation bar, but end before the tab bar.

Comment: You have not provided enough information in your question to reproduce your problem.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue like this: Set up a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` with a single cell that pushes a new `UIViewController`.  In that view controller's `viewDidLoad`, I set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None`.  When I press "back" to go back to the `UITableViewController`, I don't see any change to the position of the table view.  Are you modifying the `edgesForExtendedLayout` on the `UINavigationController` directly?

Comment: @JAL I'm setting ```self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None``` in the child's ```viewDidLoad()``` .  I'm not sure what it means to modify it on the ```UINavigationController``` directly.

Comment: Please upload a small sample project which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Could you please upload a small project as requested by JAL or print the view controller hierarchy in the debugger and update the question? po [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy] what about adjust scroll view insets option in the view controller?

Comment: @TIMEX It looks that you are not using storyboard. Do you create all UI throw the code?

Comment: @TIMEX For what I understood so far, `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true` will solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this might be the correct behavior, but the opposite of what you are expecting.

`edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` means that the view controller's view will *not* extend under the top navigation bar or the bottom tab bar. You say that your child view controller is set to `edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` but not the parent view controller.  And that when you go back to the parent view controller, the table view moves under the nav bar.  If you did not set the *parent* view controller in your example to `edgesForExtendedLayout = .None`, then it will still be using the default of `edgesForExtendedLayout = .All`. And that will extend the top of the table view under the top and bottom bars.

For the behavior you are looking for, try setting `edgesForExtendedLayout = .None` on the parent view controller with the table view. So your parent view controller code could look something like this:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None

self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self

self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height - self.tabBarController!.tabBar.bounds.height)
```

UPDATE -- To implement the same result using auto layout (preferred over manual frames), first make sure that the table view is already added as a subview of the view controller's main view, then you can simply set up the constraints as follows:

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor).active = true
tableView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true
tableView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

Using these NSLayoutAnchor convenience methods assumes iOS 9 or above.  Of course an even easier approach would be to create the view controller in a Storyboard and just ctrl+drag the constraints in place. Either way, whether the constraints force the table view under the nav bar and tab bar or not will still be controlled by the view controller's `edgesForExtendedLayout` property.  In a storyboard, you can control those setting by checking these different boxes in the inspector for the view controller:

[image: storyboard inspector]

Comment: When I create a UITableView by code, what should I set the frame as?

Comment: If I don't set the frame, the table doesn't appear.

Comment: @TIMEX  You should set the frame to (0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height - self.tabBarController!.tabBar.bounds.height )

Comment: @TIMEX  It would actually be much better to use auto layout and constraints, but I'm just trying to answer in the context of your existing code.

Comment: What would my constraints be? (If I didn't want to use a frame)

Comment: @TIMEX  I updated the answer above with some sample code for adding the constraints programmatically

Comment: in swift 3, self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []